# closure compiler - keeping inner properties and not outer objects

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have a structure like this:

```
// this is an object I instantiate elsewhere like var l=new Layer()
function Layer() {

       // exported members
       this.function1=function() {....}
       .
       .
       .
       this.function1000=function() {....}
       .
       .
       // private property
       var keepPropertyNames={

             keepMe1:4,
             keepMe2:2,
             keepMe3: {
                  keepMe31:4,
                  keepMe32:4,
                  keepMe33:4,
             } 
       }

}
```

How can I tell closure compiler -advanced mode- to rename everything, **including Layer class and its exported members**, but NOT the properties in the internal keepPropertyNames object? How would I declare the externs?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse externs and exports.

- Externs are for defining the types of other libraries you use in your code.
- Exports are to prevent your code from being renamed so that it can be used elsewhere.

### Option 1

The simplest way to handle this is to quote the property names:

```
// private property
var keepPropertyNames={
     "keepMe1":4,
     "keepMe2":2,
     "keepMe3": {
          "keepMe31":4,
          "keepMe32":4,
          "keepMe33":4,
     } 
}
```

Closure compiler does not rename quoted properties.

### Option 2

Declare an external interface with all possible types. This can be done as a record type:

**Externs**

```
/** @typedef {{
 *      keepMe1: number,
 *      keepMe2: string,
 *      keepMe3: Object.<string, number>
 *    }}
 */
 var KeepPropertyNamesRecord;
```

**Source**

```
/** @type {KeepPropertyNamesRecord} */
var keepPropertyNames={
     keepMe1:4,
     keepMe2:2,
     keepMe3: {
          "keepMe31":4,
          "keepMe32":4,
          "keepMe33":4,
     } 
}
```

You'll have to declare types for sub objects such as `keepMe3` as well.

Comment: So my problem is, keepPropertyNames is initialized incrementally, ie, during the lifetime of the app, every object will have a keepPropertyNames object with different properties. There are like 50 different properties, and objects typically have 1-5 of them. Can  I initialize the root object with a keepPropertyNames with all possible properties declared like this, then delete them? (i am not interested in all objects having all possible properties)

Comment: As long as you always use quoted property names (access via `keepPropertyNames["keepMe1"]`), then you don't need to initialize them. You can also delete them.

Comment: The problem is, the code is like 60,000 javascript lines and hundreds of files ... and I rarely access them with quotes (always try to avoid that xDD). Instead of performing such a big change I was thinking in initializing all possibilities with quotes at the beginning then deleting the property. Do you think that might work?

Comment: No - you have to consistently reference a property as quoted or unquoted. Let me expand the answer.